# Permission denied when trying to execute Latex through a system call using c in Windows 7

Tags: permissions

I am working on creating a program that creates random math problems for my daughter. I'm implementing this idea in Windows 7 by using a C program to create a TeX document, and then using a system command to run the latex compiler. I am running into problems with the system command, however. Namely, every time I run my code I get a message that says latex: permission denied. I can run the latex compiler just fine directly from the command line, however it fails when trying to run it from my executable.

What do I need to do, to fix this situation?

Comment: Could you share some actual code? It's hard to guess the bug without seeing the example code.  Does the error occur even in a simple C program that does nothing but execute latex on an existing file?

Comment: I'll try writing that and returning the results.

Comment: You are welcome! What did the problem turn out to be?

Comment: I feel silly posting this.

I didn't fclose my .tex file before trying to compile it with Latex.